# How to automate tests for iOS app shortcuts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-ui-automation, 3dtouch

I have built 4 application shortcuts for the iOS app I'm developing these days. The shortcut menu is triggered by the 3D touch gesture made on the app icon. My question is whether there is a way to automate tests for this? (may be using UIAutomation)